# Как парсить ссылки вложенных тегов с помощью BS4?(Вопрос 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

```
<article>
<div class="article-content">
 <h4 class="link-title" style="text-transform:capitalize">
 
<!--<a  rel="nofollow" href="/view-site/viewframe.asp?url=http://www.ama-assn.org"></a> --></h4>                         
<!--<a rel="nofollow" href="/view-site/viewframe.asp?url=http://www.ama-assn.org">http://www.ama-assn.org</a>-->
Website : <span class="">http://www.ama-assn.org</span>

<br>American Medical Association</span><br><br>
                            
<a href="ratingsite.asp?id=1&sta=indian" class="flat-blue">Rate</a>
<a href="../regis/chk4login.asp?from=../medicalwebsite/rating_comments.asp?id=1" class="flat-blue">Comments</a>
<a href="broken_links.asp?id=1&sta=indian" class="flat-blue"> Submit broken link</a> 
<!--<a href="edit.asp?urlid=1&sta=indian&pages=Medical&id=1" class="flat-blue">Edit</a>-->
</div>
</article>
```

Мне нужно спарсить название сайта http://www.ama-assn.org и его описание - "American Medical Association".

Дохожу до `<span class="">` а дальше затык, не могу извлечь данные.

Код:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    site = soup.find('div', class_='article-content')
    span = site.find('span', class_="")
    print(span)

 
def main():
    parse(get_html('https://www.website.net'))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: А что именно не получается? покажите ошибку.

Comment: Ошибки нет. Получилось с помощью команды  `span = site.find('span', class_='').get_text()` вытащить название сайта, но дальше Я не могу вытащить American Medical Association. Помогите плиз.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ama-assn.org/'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
title = soup.find('title').text
print(title)
```

результат:

```
American Medical Association | AMA
```

или так:

```
>>> print(title.partition(' | ')[0])
American Medical Association
```

Comment: MaxU, спасибо, это ты мне предлагаешь по каждой ссылке лезть на сайт. Там половина сайтов с защитой от ботов. Мне нужно вытащить описание с этого сайта. Как это сделать?

Comment: @ИванПетров, я предлагаю вам для начала указать в вопросе "валидный" HTML. Закрывающий тег `</span>` не имеет парного открывающего тега...